# Delay Adding Layers in Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, settimeout, google-fusion-tables

I've been researching for two to three weeks now on writing a javaScript code to loop through Google Fusion Layers on a Google map. I've fairly new to writing code this way, so I'm not even sure if it's possible.

In short, I want to change a Google map using the a setTimeout function, which will cycle and loop through a set number of layers.

Does anyone know if API allows for this kind of function, or is there a limit that I'm not aware exist? And how would I set up the setTimeout function to run a code that would load layers onto a map?

Thanks in advance for any help, suggestions or examples you may provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may draw up to 5 FusionTableLayers on a map.

When you want to loop it's sufficient to draw a single layer(just modify the query in the loop), and you will not hit any limit